# MS Access VB COM Shared AddIn Stops Access Closing

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, add-in

I have created a shared add-in in Visual Studio 2008 and using the shared 
add-in wizard and am coding in VB.  When run the add in in Access 2003 I want 
to check if the user has a database open, so I set a AccessApplication 
variable to be the application object in the OnConnection procedure and then 
on a button click I check if AccessApplication.CurrentDB Is Nothing
If there is no database open Access will close correctly after the button is 
clicked.
But if a database is open then I have to stop Access in the VS debugger.

Please find below my OnConnection, OnDisconnection and OnClick procedures 
any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub OnDisconnection(ByVal RemoveMode As Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode, ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnDisconnection
    m_oTestMenu.Delete()
    m_oTestBtn.Delete()

    m_oTestMenu = Nothing
    m_oTestBtn = Nothing

    AccessApplication = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection
    Dim oCommandBars As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBars

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    AccessApplication = CType(application, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application)

    oCommandBars = AccessApplication.CommandBars

    ' Add the menu to the existing menu list
    m_oTestMenu = AddMenu(oCommandBars, "Test", "Test")

    ' Now create menu options
    m_oTestBtn = AddMenuButton(m_oTestMenu, _
        "TestBtn", MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption, "Test Btn", MsoButtonState.msoButtonUp)

    ' Clean up
    oCommandBars = Nothing
    Exit Sub
```

ErrHandler:
        oCommandBars = Nothing
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Sub

```
Private Sub m_oTestBtn_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton, ByRef CancelDefault As Boolean) Handles m_oTestBtn.Click
    Dim AccessDB As dao.Database

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    AccessDB = AccessApplication.CurrentDb

    MsgBox("DB Found " & AccessDB.Name)

    'Try To Close Everything
    AccessDB.Close()
    AccessDB = Nothing

    AccessApplication.CurrentDb.Close()
    AccessApplication = Nothing

    Exit Sub
```

ErrHandler:
        MsgBox("Click Error")
        AccessDB = Nothing
    End Sub

Comment: This line "AccessApplication.CurrentDb.Close()" is a waste of typing, as Close has no effect on the app currently open in the Access UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having found this article

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=160433

It appears that I needed to manually garbage collect at the end of my OnDisconnect procedure.

Having added

```
        GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

To the end of the OnDisconnect function Access now closes

Hope this is of help to others